# React/JS - Certain files don't get imported during testing with Mocha

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocha.js, chai, redux

I am having issue with imports during my testing. The test framework is Mocha, and I am using chai and sinon. I think this is an issue with my understanding with how scope works in Javascript. Nonetheless.

Here's my test file:
test/action/forgot-password

```
const middlewares = [ thunk];
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares);

describe('forgot password async actions', () => {
    afterEach(()=> {
        nock.cleanAll();
    });
    it('should show a request for a password reset and that it succeeded ', (done) => {
        nock('http://localhost:8080/')
        .post('/password-reset-requests')
        .reply(200);
        var email = "test@email.com";
        const expectedActions= [
            {type: REQUEST_ADD_PASSWORD_RESET_REQUEST},
            {type: REQUEST_ADD_PASSWORD_RESET_REQUEST_SUCCESS}
        ];
        const store = mockStore({}, expectedActions, done);
        store.dispatch(Actions.addPasswordResetRequest(email));
              });

});
```

Here is the api call my action makes

api/users.js

```
'use strict';

export const addPasswordResetRequest = (email) => {
    console.log(NC_SETTINGS.API_ROOT);
    return fetch(
        NC_SETTINGS.API_ROOT + '/password-reset-requests',
        {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email: email,
                code: NC_SETTINGS.GROUP.code
            })
        }
    )
        .then(handleResponse);
};
```

So when I run it normally, in a browser, I get no errors. Fetch gets called just fine, and the file knows where the NC_SETTINGS file is.

I should mention the file structure of my project.

```
-project

--app folder
---js folder
----api folder
-----users.js(this makes the call to fetch)

--settings folder
---settings.js file(this has nc_settings)
--test folder
---testing file
```

They get imported just fine when on local_web.

But when I am testing, neither fetch nor nc_settings is found.

To get around fetch, I did import isomorphic fetch in my api/users.js, which fixes the fetch issue during testing. I then tried to import app/settings/settings, and it does find the file. However it still doesn't solve the issue. It now comes up as undefined.

What's the reasoning behind this? Is this a hoisting scope issue? How is this resolved?

Comment: Where are your `require` calls?

Comment: I don't import NC_SETTINGS or fetch, and it works fine when testing on localhost.

Comment: How are you using libraries that aren't imported?